# I am not able to load layout while rendering in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

can anybody help me out , why i am not able to load particular layout for particular action with

```
render :layout => "application"
```

**application.html.erb** present in layouts folder.
is i have to do some settings for layout?

my code is :-

```
class PageController < ApplicationController 
  layout false
  def index1
    render :layout => "application"
  end
end
```

Comment: Please explain the error better, because this should work. Are you getting an error or is it just rendering without layout?

Comment: @Fallenhero, it is just rendering without layout. I dont under stand why. My layout present in layouts folder in view. i have google about this but didnt found any answer. so please help me why this (render :layout => "application") is not working. is i have to do some settings?

Comment: @Fallenhero, actually i want to add particular css with with particular layout. i used content_for in view page and yield its name in layout. i dont understand its not picking css from link present in layout or it is not picking layout either

Comment: Have you try render 'layout/application' ?

Comment: @AntoninMrchd, actually it is working, but the thing is that i am not able to add css file with this layout. Is i have to do settings in menifest file? because i had tried <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'index11.css', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> in layout but didnot work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for multiple action:

```
layout 'layout_name', only: [:help , :contact_us]
```

You can try this for single action:

```
render layout: "layout_name"
```

You can add a stylesheet tag to the layout by doing something like this:

layout_name.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'layout_name' %>
```

Comment: ,render layout: "layout_name", it is not working , i dont know why. i have goodled it but didnt found any ans. There is also mentioned to render with "render layout: "layout_name" " but unfortunately it is not working

Comment: Remove layout false from top

Comment: @ Atul shukla, actually i want to add particular css with with particular layout. i used content_for in view page and yield its name in layout. i dont understand either its not picking css from link present in layout or it is not picking layout either

Comment: first you can do that use debugger an specific layout to  confirm that layout is rendering or not ? . If it rendering then you can check your css.

Comment: @ Atul shukla, actually im not able to add css, i have found it through debugging. Sorry i am new to ruby and rails

Comment: Great ! now you have to include your css in stylesheet/layout.css put all you require css in this file and include it on layout.erb file. same for js too.

Comment: is manifest file is compulsory it run css? or i have to just include css link in layout like "<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'index11.css', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>" like this? i just want to have a separate layout for a view and only few css file will relate to this layout only?

Comment: you can do "<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'index11.css', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>" this also.

Comment: Is index11.css'  present on stylesheet?. if yes, then try to include this <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'index11.css', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> in layout_name.erb. restart your server and check it again

Comment: @ Atul, yes i had tried in same way but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try :

```
render 'layouts/application'
```

or

```
:layouts => "application"
```

because there is an "s" to layouts folder
Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class PageController < ApplicationController 
  layout false
  layout 'application', only: [:index1]
  def index1

  end
end
```